# Lemon-Model: Instantiation of SenseContext Object

Tags: java

Currently I try to convert some xml files into the Lemon Model. I use the Lemon API and the lemon factory to create instances of the needed objects. Unfortunately I am not able to find out how to instantiate an object of the class SenseContext.

E.g. The Lexical Sense can be created like this:

```
LexicalSense lclsns = factory.makeSense(senseURI);
```

where factory is an instance of LemonFactory. For SenseContext,  there exists no make function in the LemonFactory and trying to use the method `make()` did not work out, i.e.:

```
SenseContext sns = factory.make(SenseContext.class, snsURI, snsURI);
```

(inserting twice the same URI was just for testing reasons).

Can anyone tell me how to instantiate the SenseContext object correctly?

Thanks in advance!

Add On (12.01.2015 - 17:47): The Doc about the API can be found here: http://lemon-model.net/apidocs/index.html and the API itself here http://lemon-model.net/download/api.php

Comment: Could you please add a link to the lemon api you use ?

Comment: I recently added the links to the API

Answer (score 0):

Here's the search results in the javadoc api for the Lemon API:

[SenseContext](http://monnetproject.github.io/lemon.api/index.html?eu/monnetproject/lemon/model/class-use/SenseContext.html)

According to this you either need to use:

```
LinguisticOntology.getContext(String name)
```

or

```
LexInfo.getContext(String name)
```

EDIT:

Still according to the javadoc, there's only one implementation for that interface, so your options are: 
http://lemon-model.net/apidocs/eu/monnetproject/lemon/impl/class-use/ContextImpl.html

```
AccepterFactory.getContextImpl(URI uri)
```

or

```
AccepterFactory.getContextImpl(String bNode)
```

Comment: But this is a get method which returns me the Context specified by a name - I don't have any Contexts created, so this won't solve my problem...

Comment: But this are still get Methods, so they are returning already existing Contexts. I want to create a new context...

Comment: @mrsminirobot if you look at the code of AccepterFactory, you can see, that the getter actually creates an instance with its make if there wasn't one. 
https://github.com/jmccrae/lemon.api/blob/master/src/main/java/eu/monnetproject/lemon/impl/AccepterFactory.java

Comment: Thanks - I will check that approach and will let you know whether it worked out :)

Comment: I checked it and unfortunately it does not help. Honestly I am not sure in which cases the AccepterFactory is needed at all, but in my case this class is clearly not needed and even can't be used. But anyhow: thanks for trying to help me.